# Is it possible to assign role to an azure Active directory B2C application to an signalR service?

Tags: azure, permissions, azure-active-directory, signalr, identity-management

I was trying to assign permission to an application created in AAD B2C service in my signalR service, I followed those steps on Microsoft doc, but I see they are using a default AD application.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-howto-authorize-application#add-role-assignments-on-azure-portal

I didn't find a way to assign to an application on AAD B2C, Is there any way to do it?

Thanks!!